# How can I use multiple pattern in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a command like this:

```
tac "$log" | awk -v pattern="$var1" '$9 ~ pattern {print; exit}'
```

It prints last line if `$9` equals `$var1`.

I need to use *"and"* and *"or"* for multiple patterns like this:

```
print if $9 ~ pattern and (if $9 ~ pattern2 or if $9 ~ pattern3)
```

How can I use awk for this?

Comment: Use `&&` `||` for `and` and `or` respectively.If you read the man page       `The  &&,  ||, and !  operators are logical AND, logical OR, and logical
 NOT, respectively, as in C.  They do short-circuit evaluation, also  as in  C,  and  are used for combining more primitive pattern expressions. As in most languages, parentheses may be used to change the  order  of evaluation.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tac "$log" | \
    awk -v pat1="$p1" \
        -v pat2="$p2" \
        -v pat3="$p3" \
        '$9 ~ pat1 && ($9 ~ pat2 || $9 ~ pat3) { print; exit }'
```

However if you don't need to pass in the patterns from outside, you can also do some of this in the regexp:

```
awk ...  '$9 ~ pat1 && $9 ~ /pat2|pat3/ { print; exit }'
```